# two projects using source of the same library twice

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, dependency-management, pugixml

I have a library `Lib` and an executable `App` with the following file hierarchy:

```
Lib/
  - external/
       - pugixml/
            - pugixml.hpp -> namespace ``pugi`` and header guard ``LIBA_PUGIXML_HPP``
            - pugixml.cpp 
App/
  - external/
       - pugixml/
            - pugixml.hpp  ->  namespace ``pugi`` and header guard ``APP_PUGIXML_HPP``
            - pugixml.cpp
```

Both `App` and `Lib` use the external library pugixml (might be different versions). They include thes files directly in the project and pugixml is no external dependency anymore basically.

`App` depends on `Lib` and includes all necessary sources from `Lib` (it does not link with `Lib`)  to successfully compile itself.

How can I avoid namespace clashes of the pugixml.hpp library which arises when compiling `App`. How can I use two different versions of the same library in this setting?

I see the following options:

- Move namespaces `pugixml` in `A` into `namespace A{ namespace pugixml {...} }`, and the same in `app` : move namespaces `pugixml` in `app` into `namespace app{ namespace pugixml {...} }`
- Rename all namespaces ? How should I do this? Hardcoding? or is there a c++ syntax for this?

What is a good approach?

Comment: A possible third solution: Don't include the pugixml files from the A library in your project? Or use the pugixml files *from* the library, and don't include yours?

Comment: If it's the same library why are the include guards different?

Comment: the include guards are different (i dont know) to really say that pugixml.hpp belongs to ``A`` or ``app``... (hm...)

How can I use library ``A`` from source in appplication ``app`` both having their own ``pugixml`` sources,  and not having compile errors

Comment: The include guards are just there to protect the header file from being included in the same source file multiple times, nothing else, You can use either your files or the files from the library without worrying, at least if they are compatible (i.e. about the same version).

Comment: @Gabriel Except pugixml is an independant project, so it does not really "belong" to any of those projects. Either you flatten the whole thing by compiling all sources into an executable, or you use proper dependency management by linking your library and pugixml to your executable. In either case, do not modify the pugixml code.

Comment: @ SirDarius, I would like that lib ``A`` has its own pugixml sources.
and ``app`` has its own pugixml source. Of course i could link ``app`` and lib ``A`` both with one compiled library ``pugixml`` but that is annoying because this library is really small and can  just be added to the projects, but how to do this?

Comment: @ Joachim, but what happens when they have different versions? and are not compatible. Basically I could make pugixml a dependency for ``A`` and for ``app`` and both compiling/linking them with one pugixml library.. but I dont want additional dependencies

Comment: I updated the question, as it was a little bit unclear I think

Comment: Crack open both App and Lib, and make pugixml their proper external dependency. Having private copies of dependencies is **just plain wrong and doesn't work**.